# Laravel 5.5 - whereIn array

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 5.5, I am trying to get all fruits that have a fruit_id from an array like this..

```
$fruits = Fruit::whereIn('fruit_id',[6,23,5,73]);
```

This is not returning any results, am I doing this correctly or is there a better way of doing things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to execute the query. Add `->get()`:

```
$fruits = Fruit::whereIn('fruit_id',[6,23,5,73])->get();
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't spot that, thanks for the steer!